# Why xdebugger is getting disconnected in php eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xdebug, zend-debugger

```
I have made changes in php.ini to start xDebugger in PHP Eclipse. But when i start debugger its getting disconnected.
settings in php.ini : 

extension=php_xdebug.dll  - uncommented this line
```

commented this line as per xdebug settings.still its getting disconnected when tried to debug the code.

```
[Zend] 
;zend_extension_ts = "C:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\ZendExtensionManager.dll"
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts = "C:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\Optimizer"
;zend_optimizer.enable_loader = 0
;zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15
;zend_optimizer.license_path =
; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:
```

uncommented these lines

```
[XDebug]   
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension_ts="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9099[enter image description here][1]
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"[enter image description here][1]
```

Please let me know if any change is missing?

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYMio.png
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try use **zend_extension** except **zend_extension_ts**
2. There is "Accept remote session (JIT)" '**off**' in XDebug Setting in Eclipse. I have '**localhost**'.

May be it can help, but I am not sure.

Comment: Try use one of two or both advices.

Comment: And I hope in your php.ini line xdebug.remote_port is
xdebug.remote_port=9099
and is not
xdebug.remote_port=9099[enter image description here][1]

Comment: hi venoel, I have used the above settings, but its still not working.

Comment: actually xdebug.remote_port is 9000 but for this settings also its not working. Somewhere i have read to change 9000 to 9099 in both, php.ini and eclipse settings. (but its not working for both 9000 as well as 9099)

Comment: Please try port 9001